# Parsing names to make characters uppper and lowercase

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular6

I am using this helper class which is great and works perfectly. essentially I have it plugged into angular reactive forms on any input I need to capitolise the first letter of every word, I use it on name fields however, Some names for instance Derek O'Reilly have a ' between 2 words, this class is not able to handle that (see code that does this below) Im not such a javascript whizz but I have played around with trying to concat another split such as this but with no luck split('\'')

The solution I am trying to get is to have it capitalise all words regardless of there being a ' any tips much appreciated.

```
 const words = value.split(' ');

  words.forEach((word, index) => {
    const lower = Transform.lowercase(word);
    words[index] = Transform.upperLetter(lower.substr(0, 1)) + lower.substr(1);
  });

  return words.join(' ');
```

the whole helper class is below

```
  class Case {
    upper: string;
    lower: string;

    constructor(upper, lower) {
      this.upper = upper;
      this.lower = lower;
    }
  }

  export class Transform {

    static exceptions = [
      new Case('ß', 'ß')
    ];

    static lowercase = (value: string): string => {
      const letters = value.split('');

      letters.forEach((letter, index) => {
        letters[index] = Transform.lowerLetter(letter);
      });

      return letters.join('');
    }

    static capitalize = (value: string): string => {
      const words = value.split(' ');

      words.forEach((word, index) => {
        const lower = Transform.lowercase(word);
        words[index] = Transform.upperLetter(lower.substr(0, 1)) + lower.substr(1);
      });

      return words.join(' ');
    }

    static upperLetter = (lower: string): string => {
      const _case = Transform.exceptions.find(c => c.lower === lower);
      return _case ? _case.upper : lower.toUpperCase();
    }
    static lowerLetter = (upper: string): string => {
      const _case = Transform.exceptions.find(c => c.upper === upper);
      return _case ? _case.lower : upper.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
```

Comment: And your questions is?

Comment: The solution I am trying to get is to have it capitalise all words regardless of there being a '.... I will make this clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using border archor `\b`:

```js
let s = "hello wo'rld";

const resp = s.replace(/\b(.)/g, (a, p1) => p1.toUpperCase())

console.log(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const letters = value.split(/[ ']+/)  // to split text either by space or by '
```